# Write sql statement of the problem using a single statement only

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried it with SQL Server and it was working by changing auto_increment into identity, but when it comes to MySQL, I keep getting an error:

```
create database Students 
create table midTBSurname (
id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name varchar(15) not null, 
Sex char(1) not null, 
birthdate date not null, 
address varchar(50) not null, 
contactno varchar(15), 
Course varchar(10) not null, 
Yearlevel int not null)
insert into midTBSurname
(**name**,Sex,birthdate,address,contactno,Course,Yearlevel) VALUES 
('Ruskin','M','2002-08-10','Mandaluyong City','422-5267','BSMATH','4'),
('Tristan','M','2001-07-23','Quezon','913-6791','BSN','1'),
('Therese','F','1998-06-19','Quezon','422-5267','BSIT','2'),
('Lejla','F','2001-03-07','Laguna',NULL,'BSN','1')
Select * from midTBSurname;
```

> 1 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "name" at position 305)

Here is the version in SQL Server

```
create database Students
create table midTBSurname (
id int not null primary key IDENTITY,
name varchar(15) not null,
Sex char(1) not null,
birthdate date not null,
address varchar(50) not null,
contactno varchar(15),
Course varchar(10) not null,
Yearlevel int not null)
Insert into midTBSurname 
(name,Sex,birthdate,address,contactno,Course,Yearlevel) values 
('Ruskin','M','2002-08-10','Mandaluyong City','422-5267','BSMATH','4'),
('Tristan','M','2001-07-23','Quezon','913-6791','BSN','1'),
('Therese','F','1998-06-19','Quezon','422-5267','BSIT','2'),
('Lejla','F','2001-03-07','Laguna',NULL,'BSN','1')
Select * from midTBSurname;
```

This the table in SQL Server:

```
- id  name    Sex birthdate   address      contactno  Course   Yearlevel 
 - 1    Ruskin  M  2002-08-10  Mandaluyong  422-5267   BSMATH   4
 - 2    Tristan M   2001-07-23  Quezon      913-6791   BSN      1
 - 3    Therese F   1998-06-19  Quezon      422-5267   BSIT     2
```

Comment: In mysql EVERY statement must be terminated with a semi-colon.

Comment: but if I add a semi-colon it wont be considered as a single statement anymore.

Comment: It isn't a single statement..and Please review my answer and the linked fiddle and clarify why that would concern you.

Comment: it was the task assigned in our assessment that we have create teh whole table using a single statement only and I've been searching on the web and trying out things but it still wont work on mysql

Answer (score 1):

In mysql EVERY statement must be terminated with a semi-colon

```
drop table if exists midTBSurname;
create table midTBSurname(
id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name varchar(15) not null, 
Sex char(1) not null, 
birthdate date not null, 
address varchar(50) not null, 
contactno varchar(15), 
Course varchar(10) not null, 
Yearlevel int not null);

insert into midTBSurname
(name,Sex,birthdate,address,contactno,Course,Yearlevel) VALUES 
('Ruskin','M','2002-08-10','Mandaluyong City','422-5267','BSMATH','4'),
('Tristan','M','2001-07-23','Quezon','913-6791','BSN','1'),
('Therese','F','1998-06-19','Quezon','422-5267','BSIT','2'),
('Lejla','F','2001-03-07','Laguna',NULL,'BSN','1');

Select * from midTBSurname;
```

[For example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ea5700d12c6da19687dde189846ebdb)